# Enviar datos al un corrreo

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo enviar los datos de dos cajas de texto a un correo mediante javascript?
**Solo Javascript**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar un correo se debe realizar por medio de un cliente smtp en un servidor, el problema es q javascript se usa del lado del cliente, a no ser q hables de nodejs que no creo q sea el caso.... Tu opción podría ser enviar las cajas de texto al servidor pormedio de ajax y en el server usar php  por ejemplo. Con php puedes instanciar un cliente smtp y enviar el correo... Luego el retorno lo puedes recibir en la respuesta ajax y retornarlo al cliente como mensaje de enviado.

Answer (score 1):

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) no puede enviar correos, ya que trabaja del lado del cliente. Lo más cercano que podrías hacer es usar `mailto` de la siguiente manera:

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com');
```

O en su defecto, poder rellenar algunos valores que tu preestablezcas antes de enviar:

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

Otra solución que se me ocurre, sería utilizar [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) para que éste llame al servidor y, por ende, el servidor envíe el correo.

Comment: Yo no pude hacer eso... Me pondré a indagar en la web a ver donde es. Gracias.

Comment: podés ir a [edit] la respuesta y ver cómo quedó luego de las edición. Después cancelas.